# PHP - OAuth base signature

Tags: php, oauth, signature

So I have got two parameters, Consumer name and api key so I need to generate a signature which is based on my $base and $key variable.

I have commented possible hint for the $key variable but don't know which parameters should I use to generate a key.

Code:

```
$consumer = 'name_name';                          // Would be consumer key
$secret = 'c7b0ae051a3d4846a75e339d7ad8ff77';    // Would be Api key
$url = 'https://new.site.co.uk/api/list';       // Would be url

    $method = 'GET';

    $base = $method . '&' . rawurlencode($url). '&'
        .rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" . rawurlencode($consumer) . '&'
            .'&oauth_nonce='.rawurlencode($secret)
            .'&oauth_signature_method='.rawurlencode('HMAC-SHA1')
            .'&oauth_timestamp='.rawurlencode(time())
            .'&oauth_version='.rawurlencode('1.0'));

    //$key = rawurlencode($this->secret).'&'.rawurlencode($this->token_secret);

    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac(“sha1”, $base, $key, false));

    dump($signature);die;
```

Comment: I found the Twitter developer area very useful whilst trying to generate the correct strings as you are here - you might, if you have not already done so, look at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request for guidance?

Comment: I haven't. I'll give it a try. Thank you. @RamRaider